# Where are magento attribute values and product images stored?

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I need to create a SQL query to export my Magento site products in XML format.

I can't figure where are attribute values and product images stored.

By now my query is this:

```
SELECT cpe.entity_id, cpe.sku, csi.qty, eav_color.value, eav_talla.value
FROM catalog_product_entity AS cpe
JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item AS csi ON csi.product_id = cpe.entity_id
JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS eav_color ON eav_color.entity_id = cpe.entity_id
AND eav_color.attribute_id =85
JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS eav_talla ON eav_talla.entity_id = cpe.entity_id
AND eav_talla.attribute_id =127
WHERE csi.qty >0
AND csi.is_in_stock
AND cpe.type_id =  'simple'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But I am getting attributes ids (I think). My query returns this:

```
entity_id           sku                 qty value   value
6000            0121011000-RED-L    2.0000     66       5
```

I am getting 66 as value for column attribute and value 5 for "talla" attribute.. But those values must be "RED" and "L". I don't understand in wich table are those values stored.

And on the other hand I need to get the product images but I can't figure in where table are stored.

Comment: Can you not use Magento's classes to query the database for you?

Comment: You should just use the core API to do this, but if you insist on a direct approach. You could just reverse engineer this http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/quickly-associate-images-to-your-magento-products-without-using-dataflow/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although there is EAV attribute for image it is actually stored in two tables.

The first one is `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` with columns:

- value_id - id for the current table
- attribute_id - id of an attribute in `eav_attribute` table
- entity_id - id of a product from `catalog_product_entity` table
- value - path to the file

The second is `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` with columns:

- value_id - id of the `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` row
- store_id - id of a store
- label - label of an image
- position - position in list of images
- disabled - disable the image for the store

So `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` defines images for products and `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` handles settings for different store views.